# Disable link when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

**I have a page displaying a list of items. To correct a bug on mobile, I added a bit of code so that when an item is clicked, there is a redirection to see the details of the item.
My problem is that I cannot scroll anymore. The touchend event is triggered when I scroll and I cannot see all the items...**

```
if(
    /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    && window.screen.width < 981
    && $( "#product_list li" ).length >= 1
) {

    $( "#product_list li" ).on('touchend', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let link = $(this).find('.center_block a').attr('href');
        window.location.href = link;
    });
}
```

```
<ul id="product_list">
    <li>
        <div>
            <h4>Title 1</h4>
            <a href="mylink1"<img src="scr1" /></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h4>Title 2</h4>
            <a href="mylink2"<img src="scr2" /></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**How can I prevent the `touchend` event when scrolling ? I tried replacing `touchend` by `click` but it doesn't work...**

Comment: post a minimal example with that code please.